# ApexCharts: overlapping tooltips with grouped charts

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

I am dynamically creating synchronized (grouped) charts in ApexCharts (I'm implementing a dashboard where all charts share their zoom), however each chart can contain a lot of datasets and the generated tooltips can grow quite tall, sometimes they can even overlap large parts of each other.

[image]

Is there any option or way to setup the charts to display only the tooltip of the chart my mouse cursor is currently hovering on (of course without turning off grouping/sync) ?

Playing with the options in the `tooltip` section I couldn't find anything that does that.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code on your tooltip option. It solved the problem.

```
tooltip: {
    enabled: true,
    shared: false,  
    y: {
        formatter: function (val) {
            return "$ " + val 
        }
    }},
```

Comment: While it still does solve the issue of the overlapping tooltips, it still shows multiple tooltips when multiple charts are present. I want to show only one tooltip with multiple current values, the reason being is that sometimes several data sets overlap each other and than only the shared tooltip can show what values are on a certain point.

Comment: check this one https://codepen.io/dakshina/pen/JjGrxax. I think this one is help for you.

Comment: Thank you for the help and time, but the example has the grouping option turned off, I cannot disable that option.